# Count elements from list and order it in a matrix

Tags: programming

I have a list (`{{A,A},{A,B},{A,B},{B,B},{B,A}}`) I need to order it in a matrix where elements are the number of times that each pair appear at the list. What can I do?

[image: in this case would be:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = {{A, A}, {A, B}, {A, B}, {B, B}, {B, A}};

TableForm[GatherBy[Sort@Tally[lst], #[[1, 1]] &][[All, All, -1]], 
 TableHeadings -> {{A, B}, {A, B}}]
```

Or

```
TableForm[Outer[Count[lst, {##}] &, {A, B}, {A, B}], TableHeadings -> {{A, B}, {A, B}}]
```

[image]

If `{A,B}` and `{B, A}` considered "same",

```
TableForm[Outer[Count[lst, {##} | Reverse[{##}]] &, {A, B}, {A, B}], 
  TableHeadings -> {{A, B}, {A, B}}]
```

[image]

Comment: How to say it that {A,B}={B,A} and this count in the matrix for A-B as for B-A?

Comment: @LinaRuiz, if "{A,B}={B,A}" (that is, `{A,B}` and `{B,A}` are   "identical") then you should have `3` in (not 2) in your table, no? `Tally[lst, Sort[#] == Sort[#2] &]` gives{{{A, A}, 1}, {{A, B}, 3}, {{B, B}, 1}}`

Comment: yes! I have an error in my table

Answer (score 1):

Here's my one-liner suggestion:

```
list = {{A, A}, {A, B}, {A, B}, {B, B}, {B, A}};
Dataset @ GroupBy[list, First -> Last, Counts]
```